# Method having parameter "exception handling class objects" in java

Tags: java, exception

Dear friends I am beginner to exception handling in java. I got this sample from one tutorial and I run this code its printed Arithmetic exception. If I remove that method which is have parameter as ArithmeticException then the first method called that is print Exception. 
   Please any one can explain what is happening with this code.

```
public class Question1 {

  public static void javaHungry(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception");
  }

  public static void javaHungry(ArithmeticException ae) {
    System.out.println("ArithmeticException");
  }

  public static void javaHungry(Object obj) {
    System.out.println("Object");
  }

  /**
  * @param args
  */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    javaHungry(null);
  }

}
```

Comment: The method call with `null` takes the most specific method to be called. in your case it´s `ArithmeticException` first, since it´s most specific. `Exception` is more specific then object, hence it is called if you delete the `javaHungry(ArithmeticException ae)` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you overload methods and passed a parameter which suits for all, the most specific methods can be choose at run time.

The order of specificiation here is

```
ArithmeticException  > Exception  > Object
```

1) If you remove method with `ArithmeticException` it chooses `Exception`.
2) If you remove method with `Exception` it chooses `Object`.

Comment: hi suresh thank you so much for your reply and explanation but my doubt is Exception is the super class for all other exception classes. Then how the arithmeticexception is most specified than exception. Please explain.

Comment: You are thinking in reverse. As per your logic it should call Object right ? Since Object is super class of Exception.

Comment: Thank you suresh, but sorry still I am not clear with this. "most specific method" I am not getting this means what. Because Exception also be null and arithmetic also be null. But why it is happening please help me.

Comment: yeah suresh I understood sry, Thank you so much.